# Display data in a PHP table MySQL using mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment, the data is shown in a line, where I need it in a tabular format.

There would be 5 headings which would align to the 5 'data types' below.

```
echo "<h3>search results for <i>". $keyword."</i></h3><br>";
while($result_arr = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo $result_arr['datatype1']; 
echo $result_arr['2'];
echo $result_arr['3'];
echo $result_arr['4'];
echo $result_arr['5'];
}
$anymatches=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: If you need it in a tabular format why not use a `<table />`?

Comment: @PhilCooper I'm not sure how I'd use that in an array

Comment: just as Jason has demonstrated :).  As you were using html in your string concatenation already, I guessed it would click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a case of formatting the output as @Phil-Cooper says:

```
echo "<h3>search results for <i>".$keyword."</i></h3><br><table><tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th><th>Heading 3</th><th>Heading 4</th><th>Heading 5</th></tr>";
while($result_arr = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo "<tr><th>".$result_arr['datatype1']."</th>"; 
echo "<th>".$result_arr['2']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result_arr['3']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result_arr['4']."</th>";
echo "<th>".$result_arr['5']."</th></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$anymatches=mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was initially missing the full stops out when I first tried.